# Can not update schema with findAndUpdate mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a code in schema:
Model

```
const TypeSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Title field is required'],
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 128,
    unique: true
  },
  ...
});
```

And update

```
TypeSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next){
  console.log(this.title) // undefined
  this.alt = slug(this.title);
  next();
});
```

here I get undefined in this.title..

and request in api:

```
router.put('/arrivals/products/types/:id', isAuthenticated, async (request, response, next) => {
  jsonPreProcessor.response = response;
  let id = request.params.id;

  let title = request.body.title;

  console.log('router ', title); // title is working
  if (id === undefined) {
    return jsonPreProcessor.error("Id не указан");
  }

  if (title === undefined) {
    return jsonPreProcessor.error("Title не указан");
  }

  Type.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
    title: title
  }, {
    new: true
  }).then(type => {
    return jsonPreProcessor.success(type);
  }).catch(error => {
    return jsonPreProcessor.error(error.message); // here I got an error message that title is undefined (in pre.('findOneAndUpdate'))
  });
});
```

but here I got a title normally

Maybe I use pre 'findOneAndUpdate' incorrect? If so can anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem:
Instead of this

```
TypeSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next){
  console.log(this.title) // undefined
  this.alt = slug(this.title);
  next();
});
```

I wrote

```
TypeSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next){
  this.update({
    $set: {
      alt: slug(this.getUpdate().title)
    }
  });
  next();
});
```

And result is perfect